# How to view previous history while in chrome incognito mode?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I have set chrome to always run in incognito mode recently using the "`defaults write com.google.chrome IncognitoModeAvailability -integer 2`" in the terminal. I have not cleared browsing data from a previous non-incognito session. The problem is chrome does not show the history tab in options while in an incognito window. Accessing `chrome://history` also seem to be disabled. I cannot restart the terminal or restart the mac for me to change the `IncognitoModeAvailability` back since there is a server running on the mac that should not be stopped. How do i check my normal browsing history while in incognito mode ?

Comment: You cannot. Realistically incognito was designed so after you closed a tab and specifically the incognito session nothing would be kept. Additionally, a incognito session by design, doesn’t know about a non-incognito session.

Comment: @Ramhound Is that something that is changed recently? I remember chrome incognito mode suggesting me links from my history when i type relevant words in the address bar but that was sometime ago.